# Detect screen on reason

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have an app that plays video on `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. However, I do not want to play the video if the reason of screen on is an incoming call. I tried to detect incoming phones with `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` but I could not. How can manage to do this? You can find my code below.

Services.java

```
public class Services extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver sReceiver;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg){
        return null;
    }

    public  int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startIs) {


        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        //TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED ????
        sReceiver=new Receivers();
        registerReceiver(sReceiver,filter);
        return  START_STICKY;

    }
}
```

Receivers.java

```
public class Receivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            Log.e("Log", "The screen is on.");
            Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CommercialVideo.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            Log.e("Log", "The screen is off.");
        }
    }
}
```